# How to stop socket reconection when calling Ajax requests made from Jquery?

Tags: php, node.js, jquery, socket.io

I am having a socket connection running on node.js using socket.io library.
I have a connect to socket statement at top of my script 
I have to make to ajax requests through jquery load dynamic content on user clicks. But unfortunately every time i click the connection is getting re established.
How do i stop this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post some code of you click event and your socket connection(client side)

Comment: Hi i am sorry i figured it out
I was having socket connection in init file
i included that in the php file which is getting called by ajax request